# mpdf - use another font without editing the package files

Tags: php, fonts, mpdf

I want to use my own font with `mpdf`.

The [mpdf docs](https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/fonts-in-mpdf-6-x.html) suggest that I should upload the font files to the `/ttfonts` and modify the file `config_fonts.php` within the mpdf package.

However, **editing the package files makes my project fragile** - maybe I'll upgrade one day...

Is there an alternative way to add fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mpdf` makes use of a number of constants. By definig `_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS_CONFIG`, `_MPDF_TTFONTPATH`, and `_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS`, we can seperate our own code from the `mpdf` package.

**1. Define constants**

Into some file that is loaded when the program starts (in my case: `wp-config.php`) we write something like this:

```
// Use this additional settings file:
define('_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS_CONFIG', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/mytheme/mpdf/config_fonts.php');
// Use this additional location for font files:
define('_MPDF_TTFONTPATH', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/themes/mytheme/mpdf/ttfonts/');
// Don't forget about mpdf's built in fonts:
define('_MPDF_SYSTEM_TTFONTS', __DIR__ . '/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/ttfonts/');
```

**2. Define your font**

Into the additional settings file we put our font definition:

```
<?php
$this->fontdata['myfont'] = array(
    'R' => 'MyFont.ttf',
    'B' => 'MyFontBold.ttf',
);
```

**3. Upload your font files**

The files must go into the folder defined by the constant `_MPDF_TTFONTPATH`.